# How to input number range in QGIS numerical column

Tags: qgis

I am working on some spatial data in QGIS(2.14.6). The dataset i am working on has a column **house-number** which is for addresses and it is **numerical**. In some cases the address is a **number** **range** ie 2-6 because the development is on 3 plots 2,4 and 6. Also note numbering is such that odd numbers are on one side and even numbers are placed on the other.
Does anyone have an idea of how to set up a numerical column in QGIS such that it can take a number range. I have tried the option of using a text/string column type but i dont see how i would be able to perform numerical operations such as greater or less than.
Below is an image showing an example of the plot layouts and some plots that has house numbers that is a range ie **1:5, 2:6, 14:16**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the @row_number in the Field Calculator for updating a column with a range.  `@row_number * 2` will write 2, 4, 6, .. The Field Calculator also gives you the option to only update the selected feature.

[image]

If you want a user to be ranged help during input and edit, you can add a Range widget ind the Properties of the layer > Fields tab.

[image]

**UPDATE**

You can use a small script for converting your range to real numbers. It can be use as a label and goes:

Add a function in the Function Editor of the Expression dialog.

[image]

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def houseno_range(value, feature, parent):
    houseno = feature['houseno']
    if ':' in houseno:
        colonpos = houseno.find(':')
        lowrange = int(houseno[0:colonpos])
        highrange = int(houseno[colonpos+1:len(houseno)])
        labelstr = str(range(lowrange, highrange+1, 2)).replace('[','')
        return labelstr.replace(']','')
    else:
        return houseno
```

Where feature['houseno'] needs houseno to be your housenumber columnname. Then use the function as a label

[image]

Test on label with houseno

[image]

Test on label with function houseno_range()

[image]

Comment: Hi Jakob, i have added an image to illustrate what i am trying to do. I actually want to add a number range as house-number in the attributes of some particular features.

Comment: In building 1:5 you want the numbers 1, 3, 5?
The building is one geometry / feature / record. How do you want to store the three house numbers if it is just one record?

Comment: @mapperx, you can also rewrite the label expression replacing 1:5 to 1, 3, 5. Updated the answer with this solution.

Comment: i will try out your suggestions seems and will let you know how it works out.

Comment: I tried to follow the example you gave but it did not work. I don't know maybe i missed something.
First i created a created a new column using houseno so i could use your code. Then edited it as Range widget and set it as in the image. Then copied the the code and created a function. Then just followed the instruction as you stated. But i could get it to take the range or show the label as mentioned.
I will try to look for a tutorial for range widget or could you share any if you know

Comment: The updated answer is a new solution don't mix them. Your houseno column has to be a string for having an colon in it. You cannot set a range widget on a string column type. Can you be more specific than it's not working?

Comment: Thanks, i used number column type instead of string..
I know that numerical column type would not take colon or  other non numerical  Just wondered if anyone had ptior experience. Thanks anyway. When i get around the database approach, would post my solution or work around